# Find the shortest distance between a line and a parabola

Tags: geometry, optimization, conic-sections

Given the two curves,

$$ x - y - 3 = 0$$

$$ x + (y+2)^2 = 0$$

How do i find the shortest distance between the two?

[image: kk]

My solution: find a point on the first line,

x1 = 6, y1 = 3

find the point on the 2nd line

x2 = -4, y2 = 0

but they are skewed, what is the formula then?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the diagram or plotting device?

Comment: @NoChance, yes i m

Comment: but the general formula and uderstanding would be better...

Comment: Usually problems like this are solved using Calculus, not linear algebra. Do you know any Calculus ?

Comment: @WW1, i do know calc, i just did not refresh it for long time...

Comment: If so, it is may be possible to spot it.I guess the shortest distance has to be perpendicular to the line. We also need to take know the equation of the tangent to the parabola. I guess it is not trivial. Also, this may be related:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510981/shortest-distance-between-two-general-curves-using-matlab

Comment: We seem to have a language problem here. We do not have two lines, and two lines in the plane can never be skew. You should rewrite the question accurately: You want the distance between a line and a curve in the plane.

Comment: "2 skewed lines in 2D" doesn't properly describe your setup.  You have *one* line and *one* curve (a parabola) which isn't a line.  If you did have two skewed lines in 2D, then they would intersect somewhere and thus have zero distance between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

First, find the line that is tangential to the parabola and parallel to the given line, which has the form $y=x+m$. Plug it into $x +(y+2)^2=0$ to get

$$y^2+5y+4-m=0$$

Set its discriminant to zero since the line intersects with the parabola at only one point,

$$b^2-4ac = 9+4m=0$$

Solve for $m$,

$$m=-\frac94$$

Then, the shortest distant is just the distance between the two parallel lines, which is given by the distance formula,

$$d=\frac{|m-(-3)|}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}$$

where $k=1$ is the slope of the parallel lines. Thus,

$$d= \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{8}$$

Comment: thx u very good

Answer (score 2):

Turning the problem into an optimization (calculus) problem is often a good trick. The word "shortest" in the question is your clue: you want to minimize a distance. Write down the distance you want to minimize, and then use calculus to find the minimum. Your distance should be a function of two variables.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient of the parabola is $(1,2(y+2)$.  The gradient must be perpendicular to the straight line, that is, is must be parallel to age straight line's gradient $(1, -2)$.  Hence $y=-5/2$ and $x=-1/4$.